# Win32: Unable to set Bitmap to Button

Tags: winapi, win32gui

I have this code:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {

    HWND button = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            "BUTTON",
            "Do!",
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            580,
            520,
            100,
            24,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);



    HBITMAP b = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(1));

    SendMessage(button, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)b);
```

I see the button normally, but not the bitmap I assigned.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to set the BS_BITMAP flag!